# UITableViewCell async image loading layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, afnetworking

I am asynchronously loading images into my `UITableView`'s cells using [`AFNetworking`'s](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.2.0/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html#//api/name/setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:) categories on `UIImageView` as follows:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:menuItem.image_url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
```

My problem is that the cell loads fine with the placeholder image, but after the `UITableView` finishes loading, and I trigger a `[cell layoutSubViews]` by touching, scrolling, highlighting, etc, the cell pushes `self.textLabel` closer to `self.imageView`. Here's a series of images describing the behaviour:

[image: State 1]

[image: State 2]

[image: State 2 detail]

This obviously ends up with non-uniform text. Am I even correct that it is the cell's `layoutSubviews` method that is getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was dumb. I was right in that the cell's `layoutSubviews` method was getting called, so I subclassed `UITableViewCell` and implemented `layoutSubViews` myself and laid out `self.imageView` and `self.textLabel` myself. Sheesh.